# ajax returning error status 200 and OK when the changes have been updated in database

Tags: php, json, ajax, web-services

I am implementing a webservice where I allow the person to modify food details in my db. When the request is sent and have already been processed, the changes have been implemented in the db. But I get this error! How do I deal with it?

```
           //MODIFYING food 

                $("button#editFood").click(function(){
                    var id = $("input#editFoodID").val();
                    var url = "http://localhost/trial2/webservices/food/update/";


                    if(id!= "" )
                    {
                        url= url + id;
                    }

                    alert(url);


                    //SETTING UP AJAX CALL
                    $.ajax({
                        url:url,
                        accepts: "application/json",
                        headers:{Accept:"application/json"},

                        method: "POST", 
                        data:{
                            editFoodName: $("input#editFoodName").val() , 
                            editFoodDesc: $("input#editFoodDesc").val() ,
                            editFoodType: $("input#editFoodType").val(),
                            editFoodPrice: $("input#editFoodPrice").val()



                        },

                        error: function(xhr){
                            if(xhr.status == 404)
                            {
                                $("div#editFoodResult").html("Could not modify food item by this id. 
                         Please try again!");
                            }//end if
                            else
                            {
                                alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                            } //I get this error
                        }


                    })
                    .done(function(data)
                    {
                        $("div#editFoodResult").html("Food details were modified successfully");
                    });



                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm truly not a big master of jQuery, though I've made a few ajax calls. In my opinion this could be the problem:

```
                        accepts: "application/json",
                        headers:{Accept:"application/json"},
```

Error branch activated as the given answer is not in the expected format.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing. What should I do?

Comment: Well you either modify your backend to send json, or you just try to comment out these lines.